# R: how to easily replace the missing values in data frame into "."

Tags: r

I am trying to manipulate a dataframe.
The data frame contains missing value (NA), and I would like to replace every NAs' into "." (string).

How can I do that? Below is an example:
consider the following data frame

```
   dataset1
   no      name
    1      John
    2      Paul
    3        NA
    4    Sophie
```

How can I change this dataset into:

```
   dataset1
   no      name
    1      John
    2      Paul
    3         .
    4     Sophie
```

Thank you,

Comment: Don't be discouraged by the downvotes and the question being closed.  In general, here on SO we like to effort and attempts to be shown.  Just make sure to include what you have done and tried and what specifically does not work.  If you have not gotten to that phase yet, then search around google and the `R` documentation first, then post what specifically you need help with.  Good luck

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, the more I look around on SO, sadly, I get the feeling that down votes kick in more quickly under [tag:r] than other tags.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I don't frequent many of the other parts of SO, but I hope that not to be true

Answer (score 4):

Your data:

```
mydf <- read.table(text='no      name
    1      John
    2      Paul
    3        NA
    4    Sophie',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Recode:

```
mydf[is.na(mydf)] <- '.'
```

The result:

```
> mydf
  no   name
1  1   John
2  2   Paul
3  3      .
4  4 Sophie
```

Comment: I tried your method and it doesn't change any content within the data frame...the idea is to replace NA (missing value) with a string "."

Comment: You've repeated string twice now and I don't get what you're attempting to do.  Thomas gives you what your expected output looks like.

Comment: you are understanding my question correctly (thanks for the input btw), it's just that when I try out your method, the resulting data frame still contains NA, not "."

Comment: @user2792124, is it giving you an error?  Do you have factors still?  Otherwise, there is some additional piece of information that you are leaving out.  Thomas' solution is pretty sound

Comment: in fact I get warning messages: Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, thisvar, value = ".") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: @user2792124 Ricardo gives you an answer for that warning. It is because your variable is factor, not character.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, based on your last question.  If you did not convert your `factor`s to `character`s, you will need to accommodate the new level, `"."`:

```
for (i in seq(ncol(dataset1))) {
      col <- dataset1[, i]
      if (is.factor(col))
        levels(col) <- c(levels(col), ".")
      col[is.na(col)] <- "."
      dataset1[, i] <- col
  }
```

Comment: +1 Good point that handling factors makes this more complicated.

Comment: no problem.. In general, if you hit a `warning` or an `error`, it is helpful to those offering their help to you if you share that information